# How do I install a package from Bitbucket using pip?

Tags: python, pip, bitbucket

I'm making a setup.py that needs to point to my repository.

with github i can do this:

```
dependency_links=['https://github.com/nathanborror/django-registration/tarball/master#egg=django-registration']
```

how can I do the same with a bitbucket project ?

for example this url:

```
https://bitbucket.org/abraneo/django-registration
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Your Github link looks to be pointing to a gzipped tar file. Try doing the same for your Bitbucket hosted project -- https://bitbucket.org/abraneo/django-registration/get/tip.tar.gz

Comment: To install that bitbucket project from pip run `pip install https://bitbucket.org/abraneo/django-registration/get/tip.tar.gz`

Answer (score 7):

A BitBucket Mercurial (hg) repository can be added with the following URL in `dependency_links`:

```
'https://bitbucket.org/zzzeek/alembic/get/tip.zip#egg=alembic-0.6.0'
```

In this case it installs the development version (0.6) of the Alembic package, which is not yet in PyPI at the time of writing.

Note that BitBucket supports both Mercurial and git. if the repo is Mercurial, the URL must reference `tip.zip`, but if it's git, the URL must reference `master.zip`.

Comment: At the time the question was asked, BitBucket did not support Git. +1 for keeping it current.

Comment: So others don't get confused like me right now: If you get a 404 (which you should), try `'https://bitbucket.org/zzzeek/alembic/get/master.zip#egg=alembic-0.6.0'`. Right now I actually needed `pip install 'https://bitbucket.org/zzzeek/alembic/get/master.zip#egg=alembic-0.6.0'`.